# Jmeter concurrency user with different UIID

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, load

So here is my case, I am trying to implement concurrency test using jMeter with over 100 users. I got the foundation set up. However, the challenge I am encountering is that I have two APIs on postman one which I need to get accident case as UIID that is the first API and the second API is an API in which I register the accident. Each accident api requires different accident case. In other words, all 100 users will have different accident case. I usually do that manually when manual test but how do I do that automated in jMeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqKGv.png)

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__UUID](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID)

```
 "accidentCase": "${__UUID()}",
```

> The UUID function returns a pseudo random type 4 Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID).

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an accident case in 1st request and need to use it in 2nd request you can extract it from the 1st request response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Then in 2nd request you need to replace the `21d2a592-f883-45f7-a1c4-9f55413f01b9` with the JMeter Variable holding the UUID from the first request.

The process is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) and there is a lot of information on it in the Internet.